# LINQ translation doesn't give the same results as my SQL query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi guys I have this SQL query (MSSQL), I'm doing a query where the result of joins are giving me the "top" row of newest row by date without having duplicates of results, you can find here information of what I'm doing http://goo.gl/Uv0FR The thing is this, I accomplished already the SQL query, Is Working as I'm expecting, I'm getting 1 row for each IDKEY uses in the clause "where pi.PlazaIe in ('','') without duplication

```
Select * from PlazaI pi
join (
    Select * from PlazaE pe where 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PlazaE pe1 
    WHERE pe.Id_plaza = pe1.Id_plaza AND pe1.Fecha > pe.Fecha AND pe1.Fecha < GETDATE() and pe1.Id_Emp != 0) 
) pe on pe.Id_plaza = pieepo.Id_plaza
join Emp e on pe.Id_Emp = e.Id_Emp
join View ct on ct.Id_Nodo = pe.id_nodo
where pi.PlazaIe in ('value1','value2')
```

The PROBLEM is when I'm trying to convert from SQL to LINQ is just can't make to happened. (I'm new in this world of Linq)

the following is my linq query.

```
var q1 = (from pe in db.PlazaEmpleados 
               where !db.PlazaEmpleados.Any
                                    (
                                     pe1 => (pe1.Id_plaza.Equals(pe.Id_plaza) && pe1.Fecha > pe.Fecha && pe1.Id_Emp != 0 && pe1.Fecha > DateTime.Now)
                                    ) select pe);

    var q2 = (from pi in db.Context
              join pe in (q1) on pi.Id_plaza equals pe.Id_plaza
                select new EmpVO
                  {
                    Id_Nodo = pe.id_nodo,
                    Id_plaza = pi.PlazaSome,
                    Num_Plaza = pi.Id_plaza,
                  });
```

When I run this linq2sql query I'm getting duplicate results instead of just 1 for each value. So the thing is, I would like to know if someone can convert in a good way the SQL query to LINQ Query or point me where is the error.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use **[sqltolinq](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)** to convert sql queries to linq expressions

Comment: Check my Edited post. I added another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find answer which resolve my problem, so what I finally did is to use the

```
db.ExecuteQuery<ObjectVO>(sqlQuery);
```

I know this is not the best practice and also don't resolve the question why my sql query and my linq query don't get the same result set, but non of the previous answer did.

The other thing is my query grown in complexity (new business logic requirement) have to join 7 table and search for Max dates and movement is some of them, so now is more complicated to transform the query to a linq to sql.

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 6):

Your check for the Date is different:

LINQ:

```
pe1.Fecha > DateTime.Now
```

SQL:

```
pe1.Fecha < GETDATE()
```

Isnt your LINQ supposed to be:

```
pe1.Fecha < DateTime.Now
```

Comment: While indeed that was a "mistake", I'm getting still duplicate rows in Linq and is working in SQL. I will try sqltolinq and see what happend..

Comment: Hi I resolve the problem actually neither whit this answer or other I did with "var rawSql = db.ExecuteQuery<ObjectVO>(sqlQuery);"

Comment: Thanks for the support at least I gave a +1 in this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

this part:

```
var q1 =  from pe in db.PlazaEmpleados 
          where !db.PlazaEmpleados.Any
           (pe1 => 

            pe1.Id_plaza.Equals(pe.Id_plaza) && 
            pe1.Fecha > pe.Fecha &&
            pe1.Id_Emp != 0 && 
            pe1.Fecha < DateTime.Now
           ) 
          select pe;
```

In SQL you first use PlazaI then PlazaE- in Linq you both times use PlazaEmpleados.

Comment: im working on it, but I think this part of the subquery is quite well, because im trying to get all pe in db.PlazaE (PlazaEmpleados) PlazaEmpleados is the real name in my code (sorry for this), that part is the subquery NOT EXIST,. Which I think is wrong write it... :(

Answer (score 0):

Put your SQL query to stored procedure an add it to context. Then just call:

```
var q = context.MyProcedure(new object[] {"value1","value2"});
```

Comment: you mean to declare a new store procedure and run the query?, this is not posible cause I cant create new store procedures in the database. Or what to you mean?

Comment: I did kind of this, just in case of use a store procedure I used a "raw" query from linq.

Comment: Yeah I know... I just marked my own answer as correct :@ late answer