# SQL to linq query that uses local List<DateTime> as one of the "tables"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to do the sql query below using ORM..

We are calculating tickets open at 7 am in morning.

**SQL query I have written**

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates (ClosedDate datetime)
INSERT #Dates (ClosedDate) VALUES ('2014-12-21 07:00:00')
INSERT #Dates (ClosedDate) VALUES ('2014-12-22 07:00:00')
INSERT #Dates (ClosedDate) VALUES ('2014-12-23 07:00:00')

select #Dates.ClosedDate, count (t.ID) from tickets t
left join Status st on st.ID = t.StatusID
INNER JOIN #Dates ON ((st.Closed = 0) Or (st.Closed = 1 AND t.ClosedDate > #Dates.ClosedDate )) AND (t.CreatedDate < #Dates.ClosedDate )

DROP TABLE #Dates
```

**LINQ query i have written:**

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < totaldays; i++)
{
    dates.Add(fromDate.AddDays(i));
}

var datesQuery = dates.AsQueryable();

var dateAndCounts = (
    from t in tickets 
    join s in statuses 
        on ev.StatusID equals s.ID 
    join dat in dates 
        on (
            (!s.Closed.Value || (s.Closed.Value && (ev.Closed >= dat))) 
            && (t.Created < dat)
        ) 
    select new { dat, count(t.Event_ID) });
```

Join on date not working and I do not know  how to do count on id.  SQL is working fine.

Comment: Linq-2-sql? EntiryFramwork? Linq-2-Objects? Some other ORM? Converting your `dates` List doesn't magically transfer it to SQL through an ORM.

Comment: Jesse, Using EF6. what would you suggest? I want to do everything in ORM instead of using stored proc and temp table. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally ORMs like linq2sql and EntityFramework don't play too nicely with mix-and-matched tables in memory and DB. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132981/linq2sql-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-error) for more info.)

The simplest way to get around this limitation is by just querying the database once for each date you're looking at. Since it's three, it's probably not a big deal to take a DB hit each time (unless this is in the middle of some highly performant system, in which case it can probably be solved with a little caching).

Just moving the query into the `for` loop and `where`ing on that individual `DateTime`, then aggregating the results manually should do the trick:

```
var results = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < totaldays; i++)
{
    var date = fromDate.AddDays(i);
    var tickets = (from t in tickets
                   join s in statuses on t.StatusID equals s.ID
                   where (!s.Closed.Value || (s.Closed.Value && t.Closed >= date)))
                         && t.Created < date
                   ).Count();
    results[date] = tickets;
}
```

This then leaves you with a mapping of `DateTime`s to number of `Ticket`s that match your filter for that particular time.

Comment: This would run as many queries as there are dates in the sequence. Instead it's probably better to select all potential tickets and filter/join them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do this in two runs:

1. One get the data from the database,
2. Join the data from the database to the in-memory table.

You can pass the in-memory dates to the query, but if they are a series of sequential dates, it might be easier to just pass in the start and end-date.

I'd opt to grab all matching tickets in one go, not in a for loop, as that would potentially throw a lot of queries at the database:

```
var minDate = dates.Min();

var matchingTickets = (
    from t in tickets 
    join s in statuses 
        on t.StatusId equals s.StatusId
    where
        (!s.Closed.HasValue || (s.Closed.HasValue && (s.Closed >= minDate))) 
        && (t.Created < minDate)

    select new { s.Closed, t.Created, t.EventId }).ToList();
```

Now that we have the tickets that match in memory, we can do the second pass and join them to the in-memory dates table. Since you want to join on an operation that is different than a simple `equals` we need to use the `from` syntax instead of a `join` syntax:

```
var datesAndCounts = from t in matchingTickets
    from d in dates 
    where
        (!t.Closed.HasValue || (t.Closed.HasValue && t.Closed >= d))
        && t.Created < d
    group t by d into newGroup
    orderby newGroup.Key
    select newGroup;
```

This can be enumerated like:

```
foreach (var item in datesAndCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Count());
}
```

A quick [test application shows the results here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kx8hHMDF).

Comment: doing in sql will have better performance i believe. I have to use stored proc ;(

Comment: I don't think that will be true in all cases, but Linq is a pure query language and won't create temp tables and such. So if you need to do large operations that require such things, then SQL may be a better solution. Then again, putting it in a scaleable state-less middle layer such as a REST API may allow you to scale much further than a SQL temp table ever will.